# Google Tasks API not returned user assigned

Tags: google-workspace, google-tasks-api

Google Tasks on Google Space in Google Workspace allow to assign user to any task, displayed on Room.

How to get from Google Tasks API assigned user to task? Response hasn't information about this: https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#Task

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494495/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you create Google Tasks through Google Chat these tasks will only be visible through the Google Task client, these tasks and all their details like assigned user can't be retrieved by the API yet. There is already a **feature request** but there is no estimate yet on when it will be implemented, you can track updates through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173343990).